# How to find and add missing using in code

Tags: c#, roslyn

I try to find out which Usings are missing. Based on the Roslyn Compiler response, I want to add programmatically the missing using. For example:

```
(91,13): error CS0103: The name "thread" does not exist in the current context.
(76,35): error CS0103: The name "SmoothingMode" does not exist in the current context.
```

So as a programmer I know the missing usings are:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
```

But how can I solve the compiler issue programmatically?

Is there a way where Roslyn can help?

Or is it possible the take over the Visual Studio solution?

[image]

Comment: There is no such option. The same classname can be reused in Multiple Namespace. The 3 timer classes are the canonical example.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. However, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Indeed, if there were such an possibility, the compiler could just add the references itself

Answer (score 1):

After I check out reflection, I found a solution for this particular problem. I know it's a bad one, but it works for now and maybe someone could reuse it.

Based on the Error message of the Roslyn Compiler:

```
(18,27): error CS0103: Der Name \"Environment\" ist im aktuellen Kontext nicht vorhanden.
(33,30): error CS0103: Der Name \"DateTime\" ist im aktuellen Kontext nicht vorhanden.
(50,13): error CS0103: Der Name \"Thread\" ist im aktuellen Kontext nicht vorhanden.
```

I isolate the problem types:

```
 List<string> errorList = new List<string>();
     foreach (string error in compiler.LastError)
         if (error.Contains("CS0103:"))
             errorList.Add(error.Split(new string[] { "\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]);
```

After my errorList is filled up with {"Environment", "DateTime", "Thread"} I try to find these types in my assemblies with reflection.

After I checked out all 172 projekt assemblies, I found out everything I need could be found in the mscorlib.dll. C# specialists know why.

So load the .dll and looking for the types:

```
//LOAD MSCORLIB.DLL ASSEMBLY
var assembly = Assembly.Load("mscorlib.dll");

//GET MSCORLIB.DLL TYPES
Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();

foreach (string error in errorList)
    foreach (Type type in types)

    if (type.Name == error)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("using " + type.FullName.Substring(0, type.FullName.Length - (error.Length + 1)) + ";");
        break;
    }
```

The output will be:

```
//MISSING USINGS
using System;
using System;
using System.Threading;
```

I know this will not work in complex projects, but for my problem it's enough and maybe for someone else too.